# Removing specific events with removeEvents method

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I've just started out using this plugin and I am having some trouble removing events that I have just created. I can delete all the events when using eventClick, but not particular ones on eventClick.

Any help would be appreciated. Here is my code.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

$(document).ready(function() {

    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();

    var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        select: function(start, end, allDay) {
            var title = prompt('Trade Show Name:');
            if (title) {
                calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                    {
                        title: title,
                        start: start,
                        end: end,
                        allDay: allDay,
                        id: 12
                    },
                    true // make the event "stick"
                );
            $('input[name="startDate"]').val(start);
            }
            calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
        },
        eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', function (calEvent) {
                return true;
            });,
        editable: true
    });

});
```

Comment: Did you read this: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/removeEvents/

Comment: Yeah I did. I just was not sure what id to pass into my function.

Comment: Apparently an event ID or a function.

Comment: What would that be? I've tried calEvent(id), no luck.

Comment: I passed an id from the renderEvent function, but it still deletes all events of course. How would I give a unique id for each event?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can do this in 2 ways:

1) Set a unique ID to each of your events and pass those IDs to the `removeEvents` call.

```
eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {           
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', calEvent._id);
}
```

Here `_id` is the unique ID fullCalendar generates.

2) Pass a filter function to delete the event you want.

Considering that you are trying to do this in `eventClick`, I would suggest you use the 2nd. An example to your case is as follows:

```
eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', function (calEvent) {
        return true;
    });
}
```

Here the filter function passed to `removeEvents` accepts the event you want to delete and *returns true*. Since you are doing this in `eventClick`, all you have to do is pass `calEvent`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The code is still not working. Edits are above. It's deleting all events as of now.

Comment: Well, yes - because the filter is returning true for all events. You will have to put in a condition which uniquely identifies the event you want to delete and return true only in that case. If you want to work with your code as is, please go with option 1 (I've updated that with an example)

Comment: Ahh I didn't know the unique id generated was _id. Thank you so much for your help and explanation. :)

Comment: Thank you brother.