# How to delete an event on FullCalendar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I am trying to delete an event when it is being clicked.

This is what I have and I have no idea

```
        eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {

            alert('Event: ' + calEvent.title);
            alert('Coordinates: ' + jsEvent.pageX + ',' + jsEvent.pageY);
            alert('View: ' + view.name);
            alert('This needs to be deleted');

        // change the border color just for fun
        $(this).css('border-color', 'red');
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar(
            'removeEvents'
            [this] );

    },
```

The solution is actually here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/removeEvents/
but I still cant follow.
Please Help!

Comment: What event you want to delete? Meybe you want delete element?

Answer (score 3):

In my code I delete event in fullcalendar in that way

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents' , function(ev){  
    return (ev._id == calEvent._id);
})
```

Answer (score 3):

For anyone using react, this is what I ended up doing.

```
eventRender = ({ event, el }) => {
  const duration = moment.duration(moment(event.end).diff(event.start))
  const hours = duration.asHours()

  el.style.border = `1px solid ${event.backgroundColor}`
  el.className = `${el.className} event-class` // allows showing the edit and remove buttons only when hovering over the event

  if (!event.extendedProps.published && !event.allDay) {
      el.className = el.className + ' unpublished'  //it grays out the event if it hasn't been published
  }

  const child = document.createElement('div')
  child.innerHTML = `
      <div>
        <div  style="${styles.title}" class="pt-4">
          <strong>${hours} hrs </strong>      
        </div>

        <div class="event-actions">
          <button style="${styles.editStyle}" data-event-id=${event.id}> 
            <i class='fa fa-edit'></i>
          </button>
          <button style="${styles.removeStyle}" data-event-id=${event.id}> 
            <i class='fa fa-trash-o'></i> 
          </button>
        </div>
    </div>`

  el.appendChild(child)
  const btns = el.getElementsByTagName('button')
  const self = this
  btns[0].addEventListener('click', e => {
    self.onEditEvent(e)
  })
  btns[1].addEventListener('click', e => {
    self.onRemoveEvent(e)
 })
}
```

and on my stylesheets:

```
 .fc-time-grid .fc-event {
   overflow: auto;
 }

 .event-class .event-actions {
   display: none;
 }


 .event-class:hover .event-actions {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-around;
   font-size: 1.75rem;
   padding-top: 4px;
 }

.unpublished {
  background-image: url('../assets/img/unpublish.png');
}
```

And this is how it looks:
[image]

Hope you find this helpful.
Peace

Answer (score 1):

Well this is a typical case. I would not recommend deleting an event on click. As it is confusing and not a very good user experience. People would end up deleting events by mistake many a times.

Having said that, you can achieve what you asked for with simple steps. 
You are going right with [eventClick](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/mouse/eventClick/) callback. And also with [removeEvents](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/removeEvents/) method. However if you look at the docs, removeEvents requires `id` of the event to remove. So for each event you will need a unique id. If there are similar events with same id, all of them will be removed with `removeEvents`, hence the plurality in name. You can set events in this way

```
event = {
    start: "2017-04-06T16:00:00.510Z",
    end: "2017-04-06T21:00:00.510Z",
    id: "idForThisEvent",
    title: "Event 1"
  }
```

And then do what you were doing

```
eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', calEvent.id);
},
```

You will have to handle removing event from your backend/store/etc separately before/after calling removeEvents.
Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/14846637/7816429

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', calEvent._id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Every event in Fullcalendar has its own ID generated by Fullcalender.

I assume you want to remove the event by clicking on it so plz add this to your arguments:

```
eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
    $('#calender').fullCalendar('removeEvents', calEvent._id);
},
```